# How to implement RTL directionality for Ant Design modal in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd, right-to-left

I am using an ant design modal on my site which is internationalized. The modal works fine for all languages except Arabic. When it is on Arabic, when you click the 'next' button, it should show you the next page of the modal, but it just shows a blank modal. I suspect because Arabic is a RTL language, this issue would be solved if I could get the modal to slide in the other direction when the user hits next. I see on [Ant Design's documentation](https://ant.design/components/modal/) they have some mention of RTL functionality on the modal page, but I'm not sure how to implement it. It says

> Modal.method() RTL mode only supports hooks.

but i'm not sure what it means by that.

On this [configuration page](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/#components-config-provider-demo-direction) it mentions a direction prop, but I passed it a string "rtl" and that didn't seem to have an effect. It says the prop type should be rtl or ltr, so it shouldn't take a string?

Answer (score 5):

Use `configProvider` and wrap all `antd` components in it with `direction="rtl"`. you can also apply it conditionally: `direction={condition ? "rtl" : "ltr"}`.

```js
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
    
// ...
    
export default () => (
  <ConfigProvider direction="rtl">
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
);
```

Reference: https://ant.design/components/config-provider/?theme=dark#header